# GnuCash: How to sum "search result" entries?

Tags: gnucash

Is there a simple way in GnuCash to sum "search result" entries, or would one need to build some sort of "custom report"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just found [one way](http://lists.gnucash.org/pipermail/gnucash-user/2011-April/039520.html):

> Then, get an account report using **[Reports] > [Account Report]
>   while you have the search results tab in front of you**.
>   This generates a report with the listed transactions and includes the total (...)